# Bootstrap на Rails не воспринимает размер экрана.

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rublog</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

  <%=link_to 'Новая статья', new_post_path  %>
  <%=link_to 'Все статьи', posts_path  %>

    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha4' (Gemfile)

```
@import "bootstrap"; (application.scss)

= require jquery3
= require popper
= require bootstrap-sprockets (application.js)
```

[image: Вот что выводит. Бесит дико. Второй вечер не могу продолжить работу]

Comment: Опишите ожидаемое поведение.

Comment: По идее, страница должна выдавать полный navbar, а выдает укороченный вариант

Comment: [Ознакомьтесь с документацией к Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template).

Comment: Вообще уже `beta` вышла первая. А вы все про баги `alpha-4` пишите...